# Nested Case Statements into Multiple Columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, case

I'm wondering if it is possible to build my SQL case statement in a way that yields values in multiple columns for a single row, rather than creating a new row. Right now I am searching IDs for users that occur across multiple campuses, and I'd like to display such values for a single person once.

```
CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'A' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END AS "A_NETID",
   CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'B' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END AS "B_NETID",
   CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'C' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END AS "C_NETID", 
   CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'D' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END AS "D_NETID", 
   CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'E' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END AS "E_NETID", 
   CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'F' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END AS "F_NETID", 
  CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'G' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END AS "G_NETID"
```

The above code is creating a row per user based on the amount of campus IDs they have, and at this point I am not sure if what I'm envisioning is even possible?

Does anyone have any experience with this type of Case?

EXAMPLE results: Nathan is on two campuses, resulting in two rows, one for each campus ID, with the desired goal of having Nathan's two IDs return in the same row in a separate column for each value.

```
 MainID DISPLAY_NAME    EMAIL   RELATIONSHIP_CAMPUS A_NETID 
 B_NETID    C_NETID D_NETID E_NETID F_NETID G_NETID
 12345  Nathan Smith (null) (null)  nathansmith (null)  (null)  
 (null) (null)
 12345  Nathan Smith (null) nathanSmith (null)  (null)  (null)  
 (null) (null)
```

Desired Results would be:

```
MainID  DISPLAY_NAME    EMAIL   RELATIONSHIP_CAMPUS A_NETID 
 B_NETID    C_NETID D_NETID E_NETID F_NETID G_NETID
12345   Nathan Smith (null) nathanSmith nathansmith (null)  (null)  
 (null) (null)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of data and expected output

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Ah yes, apologies, this is an Oracle DB.

Answer (score 1):

Simply aggregate the `CASE` statements. Adjust column and table name to your actual data. If you require more user level information add them to both `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` lines.

```
SELECT user_ID,
       MAX(CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'A' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END) AS "A_NETID",
       MAX(CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'B' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END) AS "B_NETID",
       MAX(CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'C' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END) AS "C_NETID", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'D' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END) AS "D_NETID", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'E' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END) AS "E_NETID", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'F' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END) AS "F_NETID", 
       MAX(CASE WHEN R.CAMPUS = 'G' THEN R.NETID ELSE NULL END) AS "G_NETID" 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY user_ID
```